# Explain how to apply css on infowindow boder thet is red boorder in gmap4rails map, or provide simple demo code

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I have to apply  CSS properties such as border: red ,height , width on an info window box.
I have to use gmap4rails gem for map display , it works superbly but I have problems  applying. the CSS i.e ( border: red , hight and width ), to info-window that is generated when click on marker.  I also read doc but this created lot of confusion on my mind.

controller code :

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
    marker.lat user.latitude
    marker.lng user.longitude
    marker.title user.title
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "infowindow", :locals => { :object => user})
    marker.json({ :address => user.address.split(',').first })
end
```

partal is : _infowindow

```
<div id="info">
  <li>UserAddress : <%= object.address %></li>
  <li>Description : <%= object.description%></li>
  <li>Title : <%= object.title  %></li>
<div>
<div  class="pull-left">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button1</button>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">BUtton2</button>
</div>    
</div>  
</div>

<style type="text/css">
 #info {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @Moogs  I have to apply the CSS properties such as boder: red hight , width on infowindow .

Comment: Can't you do it in your CSS like normal?

Comment: yes , normal css work  fine, but I have to assigne the red color to border of info-window , but  it not work properly